# Marketing Cloud Connect user (Integrated user) setup in Sales Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I am following this instructions here to connect Marketing Cloud to Sales Cloud https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/marketing-cloud-connect/get-started-with-mc-connect

In the instructions to set up integration for users after connection it states

1. All end-users who plan to use Marketing Cloud Connect to send emails need this same permission set assigned to their user record in the Salesforce CRM org (marketing Cloud Connected App)
2. Marketing Cloud User Integration in Marketing Cloud: Remember that these steps need to be done for every Marketing Cloud Integrated user (those who want to send using Marketing Cloud Connect).

But it doesn't state as to whether this flags need to be checked on a user in Sales Cloud as well? Please advise[image]

Comment: Yes, they would need this set in Sales Cloud as well.  I agree it could be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, it's not explicitly mentioned in the Trailhead, but if you want your users to be able to use Salesforce Data (Salesforce Data Events within Journey Builder, Send to Salesforce Reports, Send to Salesforce Campaigns, etc.), you need to check this checkbox on the user record in Sales Cloud for each user who should have this permission.

> **Grant all Marketing Cloud Connect users these permissions in Sales or
> Service Cloud:**
>
> 1. In the Sales or Service Cloud, click Setup.
> 2. Under Administer in the Setup menu, click Manage Users.
> 3. Click Users.
> 4. Create a user or update an existing user with the following settings:
>
>    - User License: Salesforce
>    - Profile: System Administrator
> 5. Click Edit on the Salesforce System User.
> 6. Select the Marketing Cloud for AppExchange Admin permission set.
> 7. Select the Marketing Cloud for Appexchange User permission set.
> 8. Click Save.

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_co_user_types_and_permissions.htm&type=5

I wouldn't assign Admin rights to all Marketing Cloud Connect users - I'd rather assign `Marketing Cloud for AppExchange Admin` to admins only and `Marketing Cloud for Appexchange User` to both admins and users.